# How to customize a error message in Sitecore Forms submit?

Tags: sitecore-forms

While implementing a custom login form, I need to show why login failed on submit action, for e.g. message like `"no such user"`, `"invalid credentials"` etc. in Sitecore 9 Forms there is a field to provide general error message for all errors, but I want to provide custom messages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by creating a custom submit action: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action

In the definition of the submit action you can enter an error message..

If you create a submit action that validates the login, you could return false in that action and have your error message displayed. In case of a **login you should never give details about why it failed**. Ever. Your security officer should go berzerk if you do..

But to answer your question.. and suppose you have another form that you do want to have a message displayed based upon something decided in the code of the submit action.

You can do this.. a submit action is triggered and executed. If the execute method returns false, an error is added to the `FormSubmitContext` Error list. This error will get its message from the `SubmitActionData.ErrorMessage`. You can change that value in your code..  so in the execute method, change the value of SubmitActionData.ErrorMessage to your needs and return false. That should do it.